# E-mail alias, bandwidth usage

Tags: smtp, email-server, mail-forwarding

I had simple mail server and my question is about bandwidth usage of e-mail aliases.

So i had eq  danny@mysvr.com foward: danny@gmail.com

And question is mail demon do:

[MAIL] -> @mysvr.com /* recive e-mail "means read all data" and foward "resend" to @gmail.com */

{OR} :

[MAIL] -> @mysvr.com /* header send "please foward to @gmail.com connecion close" */

[MAIL] -> @gmail.com /* recive e-mail */

Please not R.T.F.M ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have configured your mail server to forward all messages to another domain, the mail server would have to receive the whole message so it can pass it on.

This happens normally with email traffic anyway - your message passes through multiple SMTP servers until it is routed to its final destination (you can see each SMTP server an email passes through by examining the email headers). The message would just show as having transferred through another SMTP server (mysvr.com) before reaching its final destination (gmail.com).

Answer (score 2):

The whole mail is received and forwarded on. The mail transport protocol is called "*Simple* Mail Transport Protocol" for a reason.